# Webpage timing out on resource that isn't included in HTML

Tags: html, safari

I am building a simple webpage (http://www.riffomonas.org/reproducible_research/) using Jekyll that is taking a long time to load on Safari. On Firefox and Chrome it loads instantly. In Safari, when I go in to the Web Inspector, it has two errors. The first...

> Failed to load resource: The request timed out

The resource it was trying to get is http://api.pubpeer.com/v2/pubposts?filter=doi&devkey=PubMedSafari.

The second...

> TimeoutError (DOM Exception 23): The operation timed out.

It's indicating that it was trying to access `PP.js`

The weird thing to me is that neither the API link or the Javascript are referenced in the code or the rendered HTML.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was the PubPeer Safari extension, which they are [no longer supporting](https://blog.pubpeer.com/publications/E2ED9ABC8E5B56DAEB59FE4CC57E9C). Once I removed the extension everything worked great.